# Laravel 4.2 Blade submit with class won't work

Tags: laravel-4, submit

I have this submit form does not work

```
{{ Form::submit('REGISTRO', ['class' => 'btn waves-effect waves-light btnenviar cerrarmegamenu']) }}
```

but if I delete classes and styles it works

```
{{ Form::submit('REGISTRO') }}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any javascript binded to any of those classes? For instance, do you have a `.on('click', ...` event?

Comment: Have you tried using the long form of creating the array? 
`{{ Form::submit('REGISTRO', array('class' => 'btn waves-effect waves-light btnenviar cerrarmegamenu')) }}`